# How to update view after Ember.Handlebars.compile?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using emberJS (without Rails) and have templates in different files in templates/*.hbs

I used ajax to query them and compile templates.

```
    App.SetupTemplate = function(name) {              
            $.ajax( {url:"templates/"+name+".hbs", success: function(response) { 
            Ember.TEMPLATES[name] = Ember.Handlebars.compile(response);          
    } });                                                                        
    };                                                                           


    App.ProfileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({                                      
            setupController: function(controller) { App.SetupTemplate('profile'); 
    },                                                                           
    });
```

If I hit ProfileRoute it compiles the template but not updated automatically in view.
But it works for the later clicks on same route as template is already compiled and view is rendered properly.
I don't know how to use transitionTo to the same route which will make it happen.

What should I do to automatically update view on first click itself ?

-Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to block the transition until the template has actually been downloaded

```
App.needsTemplate = function(name){
  return Ember.isEmpty(Ember.TEMPLATES[name]);
};
App.setupTemplate = function(name) {  
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){

      if(!App.needsTemplate(name)){
        resolve();
      }   else {
        $.ajax( {url:"templates/"+name+".hbs"}).then(function(response){
            Ember.TEMPLATES[name] = Ember.Handlebars.compile(response);

            resolve();
         });
      }                                                                                           
    });
};


App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  },
  afterModel: function(model, transition){
    if(App.needsTemplate('index')){
      transition.abort();
      App.setupTemplate('index').then(function(){
        transition.retry();
      }); 
    } 
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/340/edit

Comment: that works, thanks. I also use foundation 5 CSS. In my previous code I initialized its JS "$(document).foundation();" after template being added and CSS worked, but it is not working now.. :( which is appropriate place to initialize it ?

Comment: that's tricky, because depending on how the foundation works, you'd need to run it each time any new element was inserted, is that correct?

Comment: Yep, I defined didInsertElement in all the views and it works.
`App.ProfileView = Ember.View.extend({ didInsertElement: function() { $(document).foundation(); } });`